# Hover over element and affect opacity of another element in another div

Tags: hover, mouseover, opacity

I'm trying to create an effect where when you hover over a list item it changes the opacity of an image (in a completely different div) from 0 to 1. I have no trouble doing it in CSS when hovering over the img itself or its parent elements. But this is stumping me. Here's what I have (I'm really new to jquery, so it may be all wrong).

```
<style>
#img-nav img {opacity:0.0;}
#img-nav:hover img {opacity:1.0;}
</style>

<div id=header>
<ul id="nav">
<li id="one"><a href="#">item1</a></li>
<li id="two"><a href="#">item2</a></li>
<li id="three"><a href="#">item3</a></li>
</ul></div>

<ul id="img-nav">
<li><a href="#"><img src="one.jpg" id="img-one"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="two.jpg" id="img-two"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="three.jpg" id="img-three"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

And my questionable jquery:

```
$("#one, #two, #three").hover(function(){
$("#img-one, #img-two, #img-three").css({ opacity:1.0 });
});
```

I guess one thing that's wrong is that I need three different hover declarations for each of the three li/img combinations. Like I said, I'm very new to jquery, so sorry if the answer is simple. I did search the boards and couldn't find a solution. Of course, I'd rather find a css solution but I don't think there is one.

**Update/Solution:**

@Jason. Here's your jquery changed a little to do exactly what I wanted. I got rid of the first declaration since I already had opacity set to 0 in the CSS and didn't need jquery to do it. Then hovering over the li changes the images opacity with .css. The issue was using .css to change the opacity back to 0. It was keeping the inline style declaration, which was screwing with the rules in my stylesheet. So now when hover ends, I just remove the inline style attribute altogether with .removeAttr ('style').

Thanks for the help!

```
$("#one").hover(function () {
    $('#img-one').css({opacity : 1.0});
  },
  function () {
    $('#img-one').removeAttr("style");
  }
);

$("#two").hover(function () {
    $('#img-two').css({opacity : 1.0});
  },
  function () {
    $('#img-two').removeAttr("style");
  }
);

$("#three").hover(function () {
    $('#img-three').css({opacity : 1.0});
  },
  function () {
    $('#img-three').removeAttr("style");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way to do this... but the quick and dirty:

```
$("#img-one, #img-two, #img-three").css('opacity','0');

$("#one").hover(function () {
    $('#img-one').css({opacity : 1.0});
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#img-one').css({opacity : 0.0});
  }
);

$("#two").hover(function () {
    $('#img-two').css({opacity : 1.0});
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#img-two').css({opacity : 0.0});
  }
);

$("#three").hover(function () {
    $('#img-three').css({opacity : 1.0});
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#img-three').css({opacity : 0.0});
  }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/KdhPG/

Comment: I don't know if it's elegant, but your code is easier for me to understand and manipulate. With a slight edit it does everything I want it to do: http://jsfiddle.net/KdhPG/6/ and here it is live http://joshmccall.com/test.html. Now I get the change in opacity both when I hover over the list item and when I hover over the image itself.

Comment: The only mystery is why the css :hover over the img stopped working when I added this jquery. My css should allow me to hover over the img and get the change in opacity, and it did until I added this effect, which somehow is screwing with the original css :hover declaration (forcing me to repeat the effect in jquery). Not a big deal. On the bright side, my css transitions (on the opacity) do seem to be working still.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like :

```
 $(".one, .two, .three").hover(function(){
 $(".img-one, .img-two, .img-three").css({ opacity:1.0 });
 });
```

it should be:

```
 $("div#header li").hover(function() {
     $("#img-one, #img-two, #img-three").css({ opacity:1.0 });
 },function () {
     $("#img-one, #img-two, #img-three").css({ opacity:0.0 });
 });
```

In Jquery you can call item by its id by denoting with `#`sign and class with `.(dot)` sign

---

NEW UPDATE:

See the final demo as you want: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/7NCQu/20/

Comment: Sorry. That was a pre-coffee typo. I do know classes/ids. But is there a way so that hovering over li #one will only affect #img-one, li #two only affect #img-two, etc.?

Comment: So I couldn't even get it to do that, so thanks. But it's still not doing exactly what I want it to do. Which is if you hover over one of the li's, only ONE of the corresponding images's opacity is effected.

Comment: Here's the page in the wild where I'm trying to get this to work: http://joshmccall.com/test.html You hover over an item in the nav menu, and the corresponding img is changed to opacity=1. Now that I have your version working, I notice another problem. I also want one to be able to hover over the images themselves to affect the opacity, which I'm otherwise doing with CSS. This works on the other pages (e.g. http://joshmccall.com/) but not the test page where I have your jquery. The jquery is overriding the css hover effect. By the way, thanks for all your help.