# Hovering over label to affect <circle> element in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making some little graphs in an internal site, and wanted to change the opacity for the `<circle>` element when the `<label>` is hovered over.

I originally wanted to do it all in CSS, but there's no selectors I could see that would let me be able to target the `circle`, and without a matching class.

I want to be able to do this in pure JS [(as I've seen similar using jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507995/hover-over-element-and-affect-opacity-of-another-element-in-another-div)

The aim of the hover would look like this (yellow to illustrate): [image: example]

So if either item was hovered over (the circle or the label) then the corresponding item would become 100% opacity.

There is a fixed order to the items being circles left to right are `1` to `n` matching labels top to bottom.

```css
body{
min-height: 300px
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 2em !important;
}

.container>* {
  align-self: center;
}

.dataset {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.dataset svg {
  overflow: visible;
  max-width: 25em;
  max-height: 25em;
}

fieldset {
  order: 2;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-width: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-color: #CCC;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  max-width: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em -1em;
}

fieldset label {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -2.5em;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

fieldset label span {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dataset">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g class="data-container">
          <g class="data-item">
            <circle r="1.25" cx="5" cy="88.8" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 0% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="20.83" cy="0"fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 10% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="36.6" cy="77.77" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 20% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="52.5" cy="11.1" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 30% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="68.3" cy="66.6" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 40% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="84.16" cy="22.2" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 50% )"></circle>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Legend</legend>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 0% );"></span>Dot 1</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 10% );"></span>Dot 2</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 20% );"></span>Dot 3</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 30% );"></span>Dot 4</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 40% );"></span>Dot 5</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 50% );"></span>Dot 6</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: What JavaScript did you try? Why not port the jQuery to JS yourself? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
const circles = [...document.getElementsByTagName('circle')];
const labels = [...document.getElementsByTagName('label')];
circles.forEach((circle, index) => {
    circle.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
        labels[index].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    })
    circle.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
        labels[index].style.backgroundColor = ''
    })
})
```

What's going on:

```
const circles = [...document.getElementsByTagName('circle')];
```

Get all the `circle` elements and store them in an array (`getElementsByTagName` returns a `HTMLCollection`]. Do the same for `labels`.

Then all we have to do is to loop through and set up our event listeners.

Caveats:

1. `document.getElementsByTagName('circle')` etc works because this is a simple example; you'll obviously need to target your selectors with more precision, probably using something like `querySelectorAll()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
2. This assumes that each `<circle>` corresponds to each `<label>` in the same order

**Edit for affecting all labels**

Just loop through the `labels` array and check the indicies:

```
circle.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    labels.forEach((label, index2) => {
        if (index === index2) {
            label.classList.add('active');
        } else {
            label.classList.remove('active')
        }
    })
})
circle.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    labels.forEach(label => label.classList.remove('active'))
})
```

Here, the class `active` would set the opacity to 100% (with the default being 50%). The `mouseout` is easier as we just need to remove the class.

Technically, here you wouldn't need the `mouseout` callback at all, assuming that you always want to have one (the last one hovered over) active

Comment: thank you @divillysausages! i'm trying to re-work your snippet so that everything that isn't highlighted (so circle #5 and label #5 in the example)  the rest have opacity 50%. if none are hovered then all 100%

Comment: Easily enough done; in your `mouseover` methods, just loop through the `labels` array. If the index of the array is the index of the circle, then it's active, otherwise not. I'd use classes rather than modifying it directly

Comment: For the inverse (hovering over a `label` highlights a `circle`), it's pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I added a `rect` element next to the circle, and made the correct jQuery to position it well.

Also added this CSS

```css
/* ADDED */
label{
 position:relative;
}
label:hover::after{
  content:"";
  background:grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3em;
  top: -2px;
  z-index: -1;
}
rect{
  fill:grey;
}
```

### DEMO

```js
var r;
var cx;
var cy;

$("label").hover(function(){
  var i = $(this).index() - 1;
  r = $("svg circle:eq("+i+")").attr("r");
  cx = $("svg circle:eq("+i+")").attr("cx") - 2;
  cy = $("svg circle:eq("+i+")").attr("cy") - 2;
  
  $("svg rect").attr("r", r);
  $("svg rect").attr("x", cx);
  $("svg rect").attr("y", cy);
  $("svg rect").attr("width", "4");
  $("svg rect").attr("height", "4");
}, function(){
  $("svg rect").attr("width", "0");
  $("svg rect").attr("height", "0");
});
```

```css
body{
min-height: 300px
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 2em !important;
}

.container>* {
  align-self: center;
}

.dataset {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.dataset svg {
  overflow: visible;
  max-width: 25em;
  max-height: 25em;
}

fieldset {
  order: 2;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-width: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-color: #CCC;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  max-width: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em -1em;
}

fieldset label {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -2.5em;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

fieldset label span {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* ADDED */
label{
 position:relative;
}
label:hover::after{
  content:"";
  background:grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3em;
  top: -2px;
  z-index: -1;
}
rect{
  fill:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dataset">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g class="data-container">
          <g class="data-item">
            <rect></rect>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="5" cy="88.8" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 0% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="20.83" cy="0"fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 10% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="36.6" cy="77.77" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 20% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="52.5" cy="11.1" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 30% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="68.3" cy="66.6" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 40% )"></circle>
            <circle r="1.25" cx="84.16" cy="22.2" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 50% )"></circle>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Legend</legend>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 0% );"></span>Dot 1</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 10% );"></span>Dot 2</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 20% );"></span>Dot 3</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 30% );"></span>Dot 4</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 40% );"></span>Dot 5</label>
      <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 50% );"></span>Dot 6</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution using only pure CSS

This may not be the exact answer you are looking for.

> I tried to get a result without breaking it as much as your DOM structure allows. Maybe it will work for you. Good luck with.

```css
body {
  min-height: 300px
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding-top: 9rem;
  padding-bottom: 9em;
  border: 0;
}

.dataset {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.dataset svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dataset svg circle{
  transition: .3s;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em -1em;
}

fieldset label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  max-width: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}

fieldset label:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
fieldset label:nth-child(1):hover ~ .dataset circle:nth-child(1),
fieldset label:nth-child(2):hover ~ .dataset circle:nth-child(2),
fieldset label:nth-child(3):hover ~ .dataset circle:nth-child(3),
fieldset label:nth-child(4):hover ~ .dataset circle:nth-child(4), 
fieldset label:nth-child(5):hover ~ .dataset circle:nth-child(5), 
fieldset label:nth-child(6):hover ~ .dataset circle:nth-child(6) {
  opacity: .5;
  fill: green;
  background-color: black;
}

fieldset label span {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <fieldset>
    <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 0% );"></span>Dot 1</label>
    <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 10% );"></span>Dot 2</label>
    <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 20% );"></span>Dot 3</label>
    <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 30% );"></span>Dot 4</label>
    <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 40% );"></span>Dot 5</label>
    <label><span style="background:hsl( 18, 98%, 50% );"></span>Dot 6</label>
    <div class="dataset">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
          <g class="data-container">
            <g class="data-item">
              <circle r="1.25" cx="5" cy="88.8" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 0% )"></circle>
              <circle r="1.25" cx="20.83" cy="0"fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 10% )"></circle>
              <circle r="1.25" cx="36.6" cy="77.77" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 20% )"></circle>
              <circle r="1.25" cx="52.5" cy="11.1" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 30% )"></circle>
              <circle r="1.25" cx="68.3" cy="66.6" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 40% )"></circle>
              <circle r="1.25" cx="84.16" cy="22.2" fill="hsl( 18, 98%, 50% )"></circle>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</figure>
```

Comment: i really appreciate the attempt! i tried to reuse it but hard to do since i can't move the closing `fieldset`